# Order by String as Float

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, floating-point, sql-order-by, varchar

I have a table with a field called 'length', of type varchar(10). These fields contains "real numbers" (fraction-numbers with a decimal point. e.g. 647.45224) - expressed as string.
I want to call a Linq-to-SQL query that will order the results of a SELECT, by this field (in its numerical representation), like with this "native" SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] ORDER BY CAST(length AS float) DESC
```

I've tried several methods of telling LinqToSQL to convert the string into a float, but when running it - it returns a conversion error (note that there are no intellisense errors, nor errors during compilation, only when executing).

I've tried:

```
Results = dbx.[Items].Where([conditions]).OrderByDescending(b => float.Parse(b.length))
```

I will also settle for a rounding and conversion to Int and sorting by that (though I'd prefer to use the real numbers of-course), I tried:

```
Results = dbx.[Items].Where([conditions]).OrderByDescending(b => Convert.ToInt32(b.length))
```

But this too gives an error.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Convert.ToDouble`

```
dbx.[Items].Where([conditions]).OrderByDescending(b => Convert.ToDouble(b.length))
```

It will generate the following SQL

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(Float,[t0].[length])
```

Note that SQL server type `float` is the same as .NET type `double` (not `float`)

Comment: Thanks, I've avoided it before because when trying to type it, Intelisense would say "This method will always return [...exception]",
but if using it still - then it compiles and works as it should...